# Bitcode for Pushwoosh iOS SDK missing for Apple Watch Extension

Tags: ios, pushwoosh, bitcode

my App uses the Pushwoosh iOS SDK and has an Apple Watch Extension. So using bitcode is required. If I try to archive my project, I get the following error for my WatchKit Extension target:

*bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Pods/Pushwoosh/Framework/Pushwoosh.framework/Pushwoosh(PWBaseTracker.o)'  was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64*

I wrote a mail to Pushwoosh. Is there anything else I can do? (I don't need Pushwoosh in my Apple Watch Extension target)

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new release from Pushwoosh iOS SDK with bitcode enabled: 3.0.9. Now everything compiles fine :)